# Vectorization in Matlab, incomprehensible syntax difference causing failure

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I fail to understand why, in the below example, only **x1** turns into a 1000 column array while **y** is a single number.

```
x = [0:1:999];
y = (7.5*(x))/(18000+(x));
x1 = exp(-((x)*8)/333);
```

Any clarification would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why is `x1` `1x1000`?**

As given in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exp.html),

> `exp(X)` returns the exponential `eˣ` for each element in array `X`.

Since `x` is `1x1000`, so `-(x*8)/333` is `1x1000` and when `exp()` is applied on it, exponentials of all 1000 elements are computed and hence `x1` is also `1x1000`. As an example, `exp([1 2 3])` is same as `[exp(1) exp(2) exp(3)]`.

---

**Why is `y` a single number?**

As given in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html),

> If `A` is a rectangular `m`-by-`n` matrix with `m~= n`, and `B` is a matrix
>   with `n` columns, then `x = B/A` returns a least-squares solution of the
>   system of equations `x*A = B`.

In your case, 

`A` is `18000+x` and `size(18000+x)` is `1x1000` i.e. `m=1` and `n=1000`, and  `m~=n`

and `B` is `7.5*x` which has `n=1000` columns.

 ⇒`(7.5*x)/(18000+x)` is returning you least-squares solution of equations `x*(18000+x) = 7.5*x`.

---

**Final Remarks:**

1. `x = [0:1:999];`
   Brackets are unnecessary here and it should better be use like this:  `x=0:1:999 ;`
2. It seems that you want to do element-wise division for computing `x1` for which you should use [**`./`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) operator like this:

   ```
   y=(7.5*x)./(18000+x);  %Also removed unnecessary brackets
   ```

Also note that addition is always element-wise. `.+` is not a valid MATLAB syntax (It works in Octave though). See valid arithmetic array and matrix operators in MATLAB [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html).

‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍3. `x1` also has some unnecessary brackets.

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer!

Comment: Done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly specifying that you want to do element-wise operations rather than matrix operations:

```
y = (7.5.*(x))./(18000+(x));
```

In general, `.*` does elementwise multiplication, `./` does element-wise division, etc. So `[1 2] .* [3 4]` yields `[3 8]`. Omitting the dots will cause Matlab to use matrix operations whenever it can find a reasonable interpretation of your inputs as matrices.

Comment: that actually worked. So I guess the conclusion is that x1 is not completely correctly written and works kind of by chance.

Comment: `.+` is not a valid operator in MATLAB.  The question is asked about MATLAB and not even has Octave tag (In case you tried it in Octave)

Comment: @SardarUsama I ran this in MATLAB, not Octave, and it worked. But I agree it's unecessary. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html ("since the matrix and array operations are the same for addition and subtraction, the character pairs .+ and .- are unnecessary")

Comment: Which version of MATLAB?

Comment: R2016 A (9.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered by other people. I just want to point out a small thing. You do not need to write `x = 0:1:999`. It is better written as `x = 0:999` as the default increment value used by MATLAB or Octave is 1.

Comment: Good point but not an answer to this question. It can be part of a documentation example or a comment.

Comment: @masoud How do I make it a documentation example? I am new to stack overflow and any help would be much appreciated.. Thanks in advance